# Getting the date only in a varchar datafield using MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is somehow confusing for me... I have a table called **DepositCash** and somehow the user inputs date of deposit and his/her name in a varchar field... The system date only gets the date today... 
Anyone have ideas on how to get the **date only** in the varchar field(descriptn) without getting the name as well? Does this have a query on how to get it by using a Like Clause?

Here's the contents of the table.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the format you have given, you can use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(descriptn, ' ', 1)
```

You an use `str_to_date()` to actually convert the value to a date:

```
select str_to_date(substring_index(descriptn, ' ', 1), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Comment: wow o.o that actually did it... I didn't know substring_index until now... Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2):

Gordon literally answered your question, but I think the best answer is to *not* store dates as text, certainly not in the same field as the name.  Instead, consider *normalizing* you table to look something like the following:

```
DATE     | AMOUNT   | DEPOSIT_DATE | NAME
6/1/2017 | 43184.25 | 6/2/2017     | Marie
6/2/2017 | 10563.00 | 6/3/2017     | Jacq
6/2/2017 | 37065.50 | 6/3/2017     | Abby
```

If in your app layer for some reason you do receive a date and a name in the same field, you can easily use some regex to tease them apart, and then store them into separate columns in your table.